# Web Application settings storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, settings

I'm building an web application (Ruby on Rails) and I need to save application wide settings. Let's say for example I need to be able to allow the user to modify the name of the app via a form. I know i can create a settings model in the database and store my settings there and use them however I want but that seems overkill, you know, having a table just for one row of information for some reason it smells like bad design.

I wanna know what's other people approach to solve this kind of problem. And also if there is a "Rails way" to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these out :

http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/flexible-application-configuration-in-ruby-on-rails/

[SettingsLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic)

Comment: I tried SettingsLogic but ultimately when with https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached.